# What is the best MSI generating install tool available?

Tags: wix, installation

I am using WIX at the moment, but keep on running into limitations (such as ability to expand properties as the value of another property). Also not sure if I ran into a bug with the FileSearch element, because it is not working as expected (does not find a file that is definitely there). I can go the route of using custom actions built into a dll, but was just wondering if there is a beter way.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best tool (maturity, features, documentation, easy-of-use) is currently [AdvancedInstaller](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). I'm not usually recommending commercial tools but this one is really good value for money.

They also have freeware edition for basic needs.

Comment: Looks good!  Would've liked to see this before spending hours learning WiX :)  But there are advantages having the installer integrated into your IDE and build process, especially since Visual Studio 2010 will probably have WiX (or whatever they call it) built in.

Comment: I have AdvancedInstaller fully integrated into my build process. They have very good command line support.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Installshield](http://www.acresso.com/products/is/installshield-overview.htm) almost a decade by now.